# How to display only the source port with tshark

Tags: wireshark, filter, tshark

I can display the source and destination tcp ports with

```
tshark -T fields -e tcp.port
1111,2222
2222,1111
[...]
```

How can I display only the source port in order to get

```
1111
2222
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this

```
tshark -e tcp.srcport -T fields
```

Comment: And the way to find it - is via tshark -G. This will print all possible supported fields and then you just search in the output field that interests you